# Make body 100% height of browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this structure:

```
<body>

    <div id="header">..</div>

    <div id="content">..</div>

    <div id="footer">..</div>

</body>
```

And this CSS:

body {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
        max-width: 2560px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-width: 960px;
        height:100%;
        padding:0;
    }

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 960px;
    height: 95px;
    background-image: url("../images/header-bg.png");
}

#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1600px;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #009EDB;
  background-image: url("../images/footer-bg.png");
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

}​
```

But not `body` height 100% of browser windows. What's my problem? Thanks.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rochefort/xkTpV/)

Comment: Have you tried adding: `html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate [stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

To your CSS.

See update here - http://jsfiddle.net/xkTpV/4/

Comment: @SlaythernAareonna then why did you mark it as solved? I prefer to use `height: 100vh;` which uses the viewport height.

Answer (score 5):

In order to make it work. You'll have to make the parent `<html>` and the child `<body>` to both have 100% height.

```
html, body {
    height:100%; /*both html and body*/
}
body {
    margin: 0; /*reset default margin*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try height: 100vh;

```
body { color: white; font-family: 'Play', sans-serif; max-width: 2560px; margin: 0; min-width: 960px; height:100vh; padding:0; }
```